# В ajax запросе, в возвращаемой функцие не выполняется оператор if

Tags: jquery, ajax

В консоли выводятся два одинаковых значения, но оператор if не выполняется.

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var jsemail = $("#email").val();
    $.post('ajax.php', {email:jsemail}, function(data){
      $("#block").text(data);
      var email = $("#email").val();
      console.log(email);
      console.log(data);
      if (email == data)
        alert('Такой адрес почты уже зарегистрирован '+data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: очевидно, там два _разных_ значения. Например, пробельные символы вначале/конце строк

Comment: точно. Спасибо.

Comment: А что в консоле выводится ? Можете показать .